# Do you know any Yii like activerecord and modeling system in node js

Tags: node.js, activerecord, yii, orm

i was looking for some good activerecord like library in node js, that is simiar to yii's active record and modeling pattern.
you may know active record well let me show how active record and models works in yii.

Model Class (having all code to perform validations and bulk attribute assignments)
then ActiveRecord and FormModel (use to make form on serve side that validate data assigned to it but most code is written in Model) are another classes extends Model Class.

so i am looking for something similar to this in node js, if you know anything please share or do you have any ideas how i can i achieve it easily without reinventing wheel.

Answer (score 2):

There are many alternatives out there, not many that give same range and depth that activeRecord does, the best i have seen is [Tower](https://tower.github.io/) which is most activeRecord like in its nature.

you should also see [Sequelizejs](http://sequelizejs.com)

Comment: `Sequelize` is great. It's pretty easy to switch to after working with CActiveRecord in Yii. Thanks!